# Oracle CLOB REGEXP_REPLACE suggestions

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, oracle11g, clob

I have a CLOB text similar to:

```
A:123, A:983, A:122, B:232, B:392, C:921, D:221, D:121, D:838
```

I want to have my result like

```
A:123, 983, 122, B:232, 392, C:921, D:221, 121, 838
```

Please note,

- It's huge data and definitely more than 4000 characters.
- Characters can repeat.
- Numbers are always unique. It can also go till 11 digits.
- Original table data must not be modified.
- The result should not be sorted

It looks a simple problem where we just need to remove duplicates in a CLOB text. I am not able to design the logic in SQL, can anyone please suggest?

**Update:**
I have found the solution by custom Java program where I iterate and remove duplicates. It works fine for me. Still curious to see SQL approach.

Comment: This is not a regex job. Get the text and iterate over it with your favorite programming language.

Comment: And you really want to keep the first `A:` and ditch all the others?

Comment: Yes, the requirement I have is to remove the alphabet character if it repeats. I am basically looking for some kind of GROUP BY within the CLOB.

Comment: How long is your average clob string? Is it possible that the final aggregation exceeds 4000 characters?

Comment: It's huge data and definitely 4000+ chars

Comment: Do you insist on a `REGEXP_REPLACE` solution? Try a trivial regexp update and verify the performence if it is acceptable.

Comment: @APC Thanks for the edit. 
- My assumption was if I have a CLOB column than it should be understood that it will have huge data.
- I just want to use the data in some report and there is no intention to permanently update the data in table

Comment: So the data exceeds 4000 characters. Does the data exceed 32k? Also, is it sorted? That is, do all the `A:` elements come before the `B:` elements? Or do we need to handle `A:1234, D:1235, B:1255, A:8888`?

Comment: Data doesn't exceed 32k. Data is sorted already. So, all As will be together.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regexp_substr` with `instr` and `regexp_count` as an extra contributor :

```
select listagg(letter||':'||nr,',') within group (order by letter)
       as "Result String"
  from
  (
  select letter, listagg(nr,',') within group (order by letter) as nr
    from
    (
    with t(str) as
    (
     select 'A:123, A:983, A:122, B:232, B:392, C:921, D:221, D:121, D:838' from dual
    )
    select substr(regexp_substr(str,'[^:]+',instr(str,':'),level),1, instr(str,',')
                                                                    -instr(str,':')-1) nr,     
           substr(str,instr(str,':',1,level)-1,1) letter      
      from t
    connect by level < regexp_count(str,'[^:]+')
    ) 
   group by letter  
   );

Result String
-------------------------------------------
A:122,123,983,B:232,392,C:921,D:121,221,838
```

P.S. you need a `to_char` conversion for a clob column(namely col_clob). Replace

```
select 'A:123, A:983, A:122, B:232, B:392, C:921, D:221, D:121, D:838' from dual
```

with

```
select to_char(col_clob) from your_table
```

[***Rextester Demo***](https://rextester.com/LEKL85282)

Comment: It does the job, additionally sorts the numbers within the group. However, the first use of listagg is going to fail for CLOB data

Comment: @VivekRanjan did you see the explanation below

Comment: For CLOB column Oracle throws error:

ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 294 Column: 13

Comment: @VivekRanjan but I already mentioned about that you need to convert a clob type column to varchar by using `to_char` function.

Comment: clob type column to varchar will not work for 4000+  chars

Comment: @VivekRanjan the question doesn't tell me that the related clob column's length is more than 4000 chars. If so, you can consider splitting such as `substr(col_clob,1,4000)`,`substr(col_clob,4001,8000)`

Answer (score 0):

This query parse the string  (searching for colons) and returns the position of the *second* occurence of the string for aech letter preceeding the colon:

```
with col as 
(select 'A:123, A:983, A:122, B:232, B:392, C:921, D:221, D:121, D:838' col from dual),
t1 as(
select col, instr(col,':',1,level)-1 pos
from col
connect by level <= length(col) - length(replace(col,':',null))
),
t2 as (
select to_char(substr(col,pos,2)) str,
pos
from t1),
t3 as (
select 
 str, pos,
 row_number() over (partition by str order by pos) rn
from t2)
select
  str, pos
 from t3
 where rn = 2
;
```

Basically you split the string for each colon (I'm using the `length(replace` approach to get better performance that with regexp) extracting the X: substring and its position.

Than use `row_number()` to get the second occurence `partition by str`.

Note that it works with CLOB of any length, because only the string of length 2 is converted to VARCHAR.

The result is

```
STR             POS
-------- ----------
A:                8 
B:               29 
D:               50
```

The interpretation is

*replace `A:` with two blanks in the CLOB starting with position 8.*

*replace `B:` with two blanks in the CLOB starting with position 29.*

etc

Note that I'm replacing with two blank to not chnage the positions in the string, but this can be easily enhanced and replace with NULL.

So the basic idea is keep the first pos-1 characters the same and `replace` the rest of the string and finaly `CONCAT`enate the both parts:

```
 concat(substr(txt,1, pos-1) , replace( substr(txt, pos), str, '  '));
```

I implemented the whole logik in a function, that returns the changed CLOB, so it can be 
used both in queries and in update statement:

```
select id, col, upd_clob(col) from tc;

update tc
set col = upd_clob(col);
```

The function code

```
create or replace function upd_clob(txt CLOB) return CLOB
as
v_txt CLOB := txt;
begin
     for r_upd in ( 
        with dt as 
         (select txt from dual),
        t1 as(
         select txt, instr(txt,':',1,level)-1 pos
         from dt
         connect by level <= length(txt) - length(replace(txt,':',null))
         ),
        t2 as (
         select to_char(substr(txt,pos,2)) str,
         pos
         from t1),
        t3 as (
         select 
          str, pos,
          row_number() over (partition by str order by pos) rn
         from t2)
         select
           str, pos
         from t3
         where rn = 2)
     loop
        v_txt := concat(substr(v_txt,1, r_upd.pos-1) , replace( substr(v_txt, r_upd.pos), r_upd.str, '  '));
     end loop;
     return(v_txt);
end;
/
```

You may find the performance for large CLOB not excellent (though IMO it is much better that alternative REGEXP implementation). A possible tuning approach would be additional logik in the function that recognise short string and process them as VARCHAR strings.

Comment: The problem here is it misses 'C'.

Comment: @VivekRanjan C: occures only once, so it remain unchanged. What's teh problem?